# Windows 10 WiFi connection after sleep

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

Ever since I upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7, I've had WiFi issues. This only happens after the computer is woken up from sleeping.

It may already have the previous day's connection open, and if not I can connect to it or any other network. However it doesn't matter. Every connection says there's no Internet available. I might add that it's always a public WiFi and the accept terms screen never pops up. It also doesn't matter what the public network is.

My current workaround is to disable my network adaptor and immediately re-enable it. Then I connect to the WiFi without any issues. This is a workable solution, but it's getting old. Any ideas?

Here's my system:

- OS: Windows 10 Professional 64-bit
- Network adapter: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6200 AGN
- Drivers: Intel NETwsw00.sys (15.11.0.7) , vwifibus.sys (rs1_release.160715-1616)
- System security: Kaspersky Total Security

Answer (score 1):

My old laptop encountered similar problems following the upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  I was able to alleviate the problem by disabling the **Fast Startup** option:

1. Open the `Control Panel` in icons view.
2. Select `Power Options`
3. Select `Choose what the power buttons do` on the upper-left.
4. Select `Change settings that are currently unavailable` link near the top (if prompted by UAC, select **Yes**).
5. Under `Shutdown settings`, uncheck the box to `Turn on fast startup`
6. Click on the `Save Changes` button.
7. Close the `System Settings` window and reboot.

([Source](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html))

Comment: Didn't work. :-(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.  To be honest, when the RTM (1607) Version of Windows 10 was originally having some device-relate issues with computers waking from sleep mode, I simply set my machines to the High Performance power scheme and never switched back again.  Have you checked to see if there is a newer driver available?

Comment: I am currently following your steps to disable "fast startup" (and am rebooting now) to see if it will solve https://superuser.com/q/1696821/74576.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me. After shutting down, powering back on, and logging in, I noticed the wifi icon seemed fine (as if it were connected), but then as soon as I opened my Brave browser, the wifi disconnected temporarily.